# Can't add multitenancy attribute to nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create an application with Ruby on Rails 4.2.1 and PostgreSQL.

I have the following models.

```
class Builder < ActiveModel
  has_many :bills
  has_many :bills_partials
end

class Bill < ActiveModel
  belongs_to :builder
  has_many :bills_partials

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bills_partial, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class BillPartial < ActiveModel
  belongs_to :builder
  belongs_to :bills
end
```

and the following actions

```
def new
  bill.bills_partials.build
end

def create
  @bill = Bill.scoped_to(current_builder).new(bill_partial_params)
  if @bill.save
    redirect_to bills_path, flash: { success: t('flash.generic.female.created', model: Bill.model_name.human) }
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
  def bill
    @bill ||= Bill.scoped_to(current_builder).find_by(id: uuid_or_nil(params[:id])) || Bill.scoped_to(current_builder).new
  end
  helper_method :bill

  def bill_params
    params
      .require(:bill)
      .permit(:description,
              :value,
              :date,
              bills_partials_attributes: [:id,
                                          :due_date,
                                          :valor,
                                          :_destroy])

  end
```

The output for the params is:

```
{
  "description"=>"some desc",
  "value"=>"123",
  "date"=>"10/10/2010",
  "bills_partials_attributes" =>
  {
    "0" =>
    {
      "due_date"=>"14/03/2003",
      "value"=>"123"
    },
    "1" =>
    {
      "due_date"=>"14/03/2003",
      "value"=>"123"
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, I have to add `current_builder.id` to every model, `Bill` and `BillPartial` for instance. What is the best way to add the `current_builder.id` to the `builder_id` on the `BillPartial` model?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking for something, I solved this by defining

```
before_create do
  self.builder_id = bill.try(:builder_id)
end
```

On the BillPartial model.